# Razor intellisense & external assemblies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, intellisense

I have an external assembly named T4MVCExtensions which is using the System.Web.Mvc namespace.
So the classes within this assembly are in the System.Web.Mvc namespace.

In my project I have a view and I am trying to use extension methods which reside in this assembly.

The System.Web.Mvc namespace has been added (by default) to the config file.

The view cannot provide intellisense for these extension methods (with red underline), but it compiles without runtime extensions.

How can I make sure that intellisense works correctly?

Answer (score 3):

The output folder was set to a different folder (plugin architecture).
Razor expects references to be present in the BIN folder.
I adapted the project so that the output folder is the normal one.
Post-build events will copy the dll files towards the other folder.

So make sure references are always in the BIN folder for Razor.